# Which city is pictured in this scene from Line of Duty S6E1?

Tags: uk, identify-this, northern-ireland

This screenshot is taken from the S6E1 of the BBC series *[Line of Duty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_of_Duty)*. It’s taken from the 4:25 mark (approximately).

[image]

Apologies for the poor resolution.

I’m guessing [Midlands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midlands) / [North of England](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northern_England). The red brick terraced houses with the occasional out-of-place multi-story housing block reminds me of areas of Nottingham, but many cities look like that so it could just as easily be Manchester, Grimsby, Liverpool, etc.

Comment: I think this is also on topic on Movies & TV. That doesn’t make it off topic here!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Based on the replies to [this tweet](https://twitter.com/EamonnHolmes/status/1373745728544210945?s=20), it is the exit of [Corpus Christi College, Belfast](https://goo.gl/maps/gLQRLi1TWYoDUQC66):

[image]

The colour of the houses match, as does the external pipe on the end of the left terrace.

Looking in the other direction using Google Street View, one sees gates opening into the college:

[image: l]

I think the tower to the centre left is City Hospital, with its chimney in front, and the towers to the right are [2 of the 3 towers by the Park Centre](https://goo.gl/maps/Vw7aS96udZxaU6D76)

Comment: Here's [my attempt](https://imgur.com/a/jMyVGq3) to re-create the view using Google Maps' 3D capabilities.  It seems to match up pretty well.  (Unfortunately, I can't seem to directly link to 3D views.)

Comment: It appears that the red brick church steeple in the middle distance is the Cultúrlann Mc Adam Ó Fiaich (an Irish-language cultural center), and the blue-roofed white building towards the left of the frame is a warehouse on Shiels St.